# Android custom view onDraw not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view that is added via xml:

```
<com.my.app.views.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
```

What I'm trying to do is draw the view so that it:

- contains a black bar in the middle of itself
- is positioned at the half way point of the Activity in which it's inflated
- has a height that is calculated in the Activity in which it's inflated

To that end, here's what I've tried:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    public Context context;
    public int barViewWidth;
    public int barViewHeight;
    public int deviceHeight;

    public final static double LINE_STROKE = 20.0;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);

        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Timber.i("onDraw %s", "WHOOPS");

        setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        paint.setStrokeWidth((int)LINE_STROKE);

        float startX = 0.0f;

        Timber.i("deviceHeight %d", deviceHeight);
        Timber.i("barViewHeight %d", barViewHeight);
        Timber.i("barViewWidth %d", barViewWidth);

        double yOrigin = (deviceHeight / 2) - (barViewHeight / 2);
        float startY = (float)yOrigin;

        float stopX = barViewWidth;
        float stopY = (float)yOrigin + (float)LINE_STROKE;

        Timber.i("startX %s", Float.toString(startX));
        Timber.i("startY %s", Float.toString(startY));
        Timber.i("stopX %s", Float.toString(stopX));
        Timber.i("stopY %s", Float.toString(stopY));

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width;
        int height;

        int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        barViewWidth = widthSize;

        Timber.i("onMeasure barViewHeight %d", barViewHeight);

        width = widthSize;
        height = barViewHeight;

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    public void setHeight(int activityHeight, int segmentHeight) {
        this.deviceHeight = activityHeight;
        this.barViewHeight = segmentHeight;
    }
}
```

`setHeight()` gets called from the Activity:

```
customView.setHeight(height(), viewHeight());
```

I know the values seem to be setting as this is what my `Timber` output shows:

```
onMeasure barViewHeight 107
onDraw WHOOPS
deviceHeight 1184
barViewHeight 107
barViewWidth 720
startX 0.0
startY 539.0
stopX 720.0
stopY 559.0
onMeasure barViewHeight 107
onDraw WHOOPS
deviceHeight 1184
barViewHeight 107
barViewWidth 720
startX 0.0
startY 539.0
stopX 720.0
stopY 559.0
```

However the View isn't actually showing despite the numbers seeming okay. I also seem to be calling `onMeasure()` and therefore `onDraw()` twice, but that's not my main concern. Maybe that'd help explain why things don't seem to be drawing properly though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
barViewHeight 107
barViewWidth 720
startX 0.0
startY 539.0
stopX 720.0
stopY 559.0
```

Seems you are drawing the line outside of the visible range.

Height is 107 but startY = 539 and stopY = 559